# How to make chronometer run when switched between activities

Tags: android, chronometer

I have chronometer that only works if we are present in that particular activity now if i want to switch to other activity keeping the chronometer working continuously what must be done here is my code till now what i have implemented.
Thanks In advance!!!

```
 package com.example.home.outdoor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import static android.support.v7.recyclerview.R.attr.layoutManager;
public class Adap1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adap1.ViewHolder>
{
    String a121[] = new String[10];
    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdap";
    private String[] titles = {"Distance",
            "Duration"};
    Context avd;
    private long timeWhenStopped = 0;
    private boolean stopClicked;
    private int ads[] = {0, 1};
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton a1s, a2s;
    Chronometer chronometer;
    public static final int WeatherVe = 0;
    public static final int ChronoVe = 1;

    public Adap1(String a121[]) {
        this.a121 = a121;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

        }
    }

    public class WeatherVe extends ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemTitle;
        ImageView acv;
        public TextView itemg;

        public WeatherVe(View v) {

            super(v);
            itemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ass);
            itemg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ass1);
        }
    }

    public class ChronoVe extends ViewHolder {


        public ChronoVe(View v) {

            super(v);
            a1s = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.as);
            a2s = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.as1);
            chronometer = (Chronometer) v.findViewById(R.id.ch);
            chronometer.setText("00:10");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        View v;
        if (viewType == WeatherVe) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_lay12, parent, false);
            return new WeatherVe(v);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card123, parent, false);
            return new ChronoVe(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == WeatherVe) {
            WeatherVe hsolder = (WeatherVe) holder;
            // CustomAdap.WeatherViewHolder holder = (CustomAdap.WeatherViewHolder) viewHolder;
            hsolder.itemTitle.setText(a121[position]);
            hsolder.itemg.setText(a121[position + 1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("here dudeeeeeeeeeeeee");
            //  CustomAdap.ScoreViewHolder holder = (CustomAdap.ScoreViewHolder) viewHolder;
            ChronoVe hags = (ChronoVe) holder;
          //  new chronom().execute();
     a1s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                a2s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
startButtonClick(v);
                }
            });
            a2s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopButtonClick(v);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titles.length;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return ads[position];
    }

    private void showElapsedTime() {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    //    Toast.makeText(ChronoExample.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + elapsedMillis,
      //          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // the method for when we press the 'start' button
    public void startButtonClick(View v) {
        int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

        String chronoText = chronometer.getText().toString();
        String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
        if (array.length == 2) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
        } else if (array.length == 3) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                    + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
        }

        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
        chronometer.start();

    }

    // the method for when we press the 'stop' button
    public void stopButtonClick(View v) {
        if (!stopClicked) {
            chronometer.stop();
            showElapsedTime();
        }

    }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid UI reload

Solution

```
private View rootView;// Cache view

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");

        if (rootView == null)
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, null);
        }
        // Cached rootView need to determine whether the parent has been added, if there is parent needs to be deleted from parent, or else will happen this rootview has a parent error. 
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```